# How to find out which devices are (not) compatible with my Android App?

Tags: android, compatibility, google-play

we have developed and Android app, first time, great fun. Now we are giving it to friends and at first everything seems alright. But two guys with fairly modern phones (one is a Desire HD) claim, that the market greys out the app and says it wouldn't be compatible with the device.

That is odd to me, because I can install it from the market on very low-end devices (e.g., tested with Huawei U8650).

The relevant part of the Manifest.xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.android.app"
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="0.1" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="15"
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<supports-screens 
                android:largeScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:smallScreens="true"
                android:anyDensity="true"/>

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity>
      ...
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

What am I missing?

Is there a website/feature/tool that let's me check out compatibility with existing devices (i.e., match known requested features of devices against my app)? I took a look with aapt which tells me nothing I didn't know from the Manifest.

Help highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a cool menu in your Android Market console:

Click on the show device link ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, found it by really searching on the site! ... for everybody else: it's below the very long lists of countries!

Comment: Is it also possible to access that information for any other third-party apps?